# How to convert from a Hybris enumtype to a Java Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar, type-conversion, enumeration, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris, I created an **enumeration** of days of week.

Here is my code:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek implements HybrisEnumValue
{
    SUNDAY("SUNDAY"),
    MONDAY("MONDAY"),
    TUESDAY("TUESDAY"),
    WEDNESDAY("WEDNESDAY"),
    THURSDAY("THURSDAY"),
    FRIDAY("FRIDAY"),
    SATURDAY("SATURDAY");
}
```

How can I convert this enumeration to a Calendar in Java, so as I can compare between **Hybris enumeration** and **Java Calendar** values?

Comment: I recommend you neither use `Calendar` nor your own enum. `Calendar` is poorly designed and long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It has a built-in `DayOfWeek` enum similar to yours.

Comment: Which comparison had you got in mind? If you convert your enum value of `TUESDAY` (for example) to a `Calendar` object also representing some Tuesday, it most likely will not be equal to your existing `Calendar` also rpresenting some Tuesday, and you don't know which is earlier or later. So what comparison makes sense to make?

Comment: Provide a link to the documentation for `HybrisEnumValue`. I cannot find robust documentation on the SAP web site, just partial info on  pages such as [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c895989866910148d6a802f06651702.html?q=HybrisEnumValue). And explain more about exactly what you want -- your Question is not clear.

Comment: @BasilBourque That's the correct reference. Hybris enums are not created manually (by creating a Java file). The Hybris enum is defined in an XML file, and its Java files/classes are autogenerated during the build. (He's showing part of the autogenerated Java enum). Also, a lot Hybris APIs use the Calendar classes. So, the newer Java 8 Date/Time APIs aren't relevant.

Comment: Thanks, @geffchang, for your insightful comment. I cannot agree that *the newer Java 8 Date/Time APIs aren't relevant*, though. As I demonstrate in my answer, easy conversions to and from the modern `ZonedDateTime` exist. I’d prefer to use them any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate Hybris does not have an OOTB service / utility for such kind of conversion. If you look at the OOTB `de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.impl.DefaultTriggerService`, it has a `DAYS_OF_WEEK_MAP` hashmap to deal with this.

You could probably create your own service / utility to do something similar. Here's something I thought of, to convert from Hybris enum to Calendar int (for week), or from Calendar object or int to Hybris enum. You could probably adjust it to become more flexible.

```
enum HybrisDaysOfWeek implements HybrisEnumValue
{
    SUNDAY("SUNDAY"),
    MONDAY("MONDAY"),
    TUESDAY("TUESDAY"),
    WEDNESDAY("WEDNESDAY"),
    THURSDAY("THURSDAY"),
    FRIDAY("FRIDAY"),
    SATURDAY("SATURDAY");

    private final String code;

    private HybrisDaysOfWeek(final String code)
    {
        this.code = code.intern();
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        return this.code;
    }
}

class CalendarUtil {

    private CalendarUtil() {
        // do not instantiate
    }

    public static final HybrisDaysOfWeek toHybrisDaysOfWeek(Calendar calendar) {
        return HybrisDaysOfWeek.values()[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1];
    }

    public static final HybrisDaysOfWeek toHybrisDaysOfWeek(int dayOfWeek) {
        return HybrisDaysOfWeek.values()[dayOfWeek - 1];
    }

    public static final int toCalendarDayOfWeek(HybrisDaysOfWeek week) {
        return week.ordinal() + 1;
    }
}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("### Calendar Object to Hybris:");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Prints Sunday (Calendar value: 1)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(cal));
        // Prints Monday (Calendar value: 2)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(cal));   
        // Prints Friday (Calendar value: 6)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(cal));
        // Prints Saturday (Calendar value: 7)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(cal));

        System.out.println("### Calendar int to Hybris:");
        // Prints Sunday (Calendar value: 1)
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY));
        // Prints Monday (Calendar value: 2)
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY));
        // Prints Friday (Calendar value: 6)
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(Calendar.FRIDAY));
        // Prints Saturday (Calendar value: 7)
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toHybrisDaysOfWeek(Calendar.SATURDAY));

        System.out.println("### Hybris enum to Calendar int:");
        // Prints 1
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toCalendarDayOfWeek(HybrisDaysOfWeek.SUNDAY));
        // Prints 2
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toCalendarDayOfWeek(HybrisDaysOfWeek.MONDAY));
        // Prints 6
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toCalendarDayOfWeek(HybrisDaysOfWeek.FRIDAY));
        // Prints 7
        System.out.println(CalendarUtil.toCalendarDayOfWeek(HybrisDaysOfWeek.SATURDAY));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. It already has a built-in `DayOfWeek` enum similar to yours (only begins with `MONDAY` in agreement with the international standard). Which class to use instead of the old `Calendar` depends on your exact requirements. For example, for a day without time of day use `LocalDate`. For a date and time in a specific time zone use `ZonedDateTime`. Here’s an example of code using `LocalDate`:

```
    DayOfWeek givenDow = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY; // java.time DayOfWeek
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JUNE, 2);
    DayOfWeek dowOfDate = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (dowOfDate.equals(givenDow)) {
        System.out.println("Yes, it’s a Tuesday");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No, it’s a " + dowOfDate);
    }
```

Output is:

> Yes, it’s a Tuesday

I did think about whether you wanted a comparison to tell you whether the date was before or after Tuesday, but since Tuesdays come every week, I didn’t find it very meaningful for most purposes. Let me know if it is for yours.

It’s always the question whether you want to use `equals()` or `==` for comparing enum values. Both work since the compuiler ensure that each enum constant is a singleton. On Stack Overflow I tend to use `equals()` because it’s generally recommended for comparing objects for equality, and someone using `==` between non-enum objects risks an unpleasant surprise. The project standard where I work says to use `==` for comparing enum values.

If you’ve got a `GregorianCalendar` object from a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now, you may convert to `ZonedDateTime` and get its day of week as a java.time enum constant:

```
    GregorianCalendar oldfashionedCalendar
            = new GregorianCalendar(2020, Calendar.JUNE, 3);

    DayOfWeek dowOfCalendar = oldfashionedCalendar.toZonedDateTime().getDayOfWeek();
```

The rest is as before. The `Calendar` that you have got is by far most likely a `GregorianCalendar`, and if so, you may cast it to one.

### Converting to Calendar

I don’t know what sense it makes, but of course a `DayOfWeek` value can be converted to an old-fashioned `Calendar`. We need to decide what we want all the other `Calendar` fields to be. Here’s an example:

```
    DayOfWeek givenDow = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;

    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = LocalDate.EPOCH
            .with(givenDow)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Calendar oldfashionedCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(startOfDay);

    System.out.println(oldfashionedCalendar.getTime());
```

> Tue Dec 30 00:00:00 CET 1969

So we’ve got a Tuesday as requested.

### Using your Hybris enum

If you insist on using your own enum, we can convert that too. To convert to a java.time enum we need to take into account that your enum has Sunday first while java.time has got it last:

```
    DaysOfWeek givenDow = DaysOfWeek.TUESDAY; // Your Hybris DaysOfWeek

    DayOfWeek javaDow;
    if (givenDow.equals(DaysOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
        javaDow = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;
    } else {
        // The ordinal of Hybris DaysOfWeek for Monday through Saturday are 1 through 6,
        // which agrees with Java DayOfWeek numbering
        javaDow = DayOfWeek.of(givenDow.ordinal());
    }
    System.out.println("As java.time DayOfWeek: " + javaDow);
```

> As java.time DayOfWeek: TUESDAY

To convert it to something that you can meaningfully compare with a `Calendar` we need to add 1 to the ordinal because `Calendar` numbers the days from 1. Sunday poses no problem, it comes first in both `DaysOfWeek` and `Calendar`.

```
    int givenCalendarDow = givenDow.ordinal() + 1;
    GregorianCalendar oldfashionedCalendar
            = new GregorianCalendar(2020, Calendar.JUNE, 9);
    int dowOfCalendar = oldfashionedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dowOfCalendar == givenCalendarDow) {
        System.out.println("Yes, it’s a Tuesday");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No, it’s a " + dowOfCalendar);
    }
```

> Yes, it’s a Tuesday

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.